# How to get year from timestamp in presto sql?

Tags: presto

I have the following query and would like to extract the year from login_time. login_time is in timestamp format (i.e. 2019-03-12 08:51:35.000)

```
Select year(from_unixtime(cast(login_time as int))) from profile limit 100
```

There is an error - cannot cast timestamp to integer when I run this query. Does anyone know what's the reason for it? Would appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is an error - cannot cast timestamp to integer

This suggests the `login_time` is of `timestamp` data type, so you should just call [`year()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#year) on it:

```
year(login_time)
```

Comment: `from_unixtime` expects a number, and based on the error message, `login_time` is a `timestamp`